# Constructing array of C++ vectors of different types

Tags: c++, vector, types

Is there a nice way to construct an array of std::vectors of different types? Also Is there a good way of storing those vectors?

For example, let us have some structs `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. I want to make a container class `Cont` that hold some combination of `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` vectors. The following code will achieve this, but I have some problems with it.

```
#include <vector>

// arbitrary structs
struct Foo{ int var1; };
struct Bar{ double var1; double var2; };
struct Baz{ char var1; float var2; };

enum Mask{
    fooMask = (1<<0),
    barMask = (1<<1),
    bazMask = (1<<2)
};

class Cont{
    void** containers;

public:
    Cont(int mask){
        // count number of 1s in mask
        int count = 0;
        int countMask = mask;
        while(countMask){
            countMask &= countMask-1; // unset rightmost 1
            count++;
        }

        containers = new void*[count];

        int index = 0;
        if((mask & fooMask) == fooMask)
            containers[index++] = new std::vector<Foo>;
        if((mask & barMask) == barMask)
            containers[index++] = new std::vector<Bar>;
        if((mask & bazMask) == bazMask)
            containers[index++] = new std::vector<Baz>;
    }
};

int main(){
    // example construction
    Cont c1(fooMask);
    Cont c2(barMask|bazMask);

    return 0;
}
```

First, I don't like that I have to store the array of vectors in a void** but I could not figure out a better way.

Second, if I add a new struct called `Qux`, I would have to modify the `Cont` constructor. Preferably for maintainability, I would want to construct the array without having to hardcode the struct types into the `Cont` class.

I've tried to use templates to solve this problem, but couldn't find a solution I was happy with. I'm concerned about making `Cont` a template as I think it will lead to template bloat for each combination of structs. Also I will have multiple `Cont` objects but only one of each combination that I need.

Comment: There’s `std::any`.

Comment: `std::variant` too. And rather use a `vector<vector<variant<Foo, Bar, Baz>>` than a void ptr. At the very least a `vector<vector<...>>`

Comment: What's your use case? It's usually a bad idea to have containers of unrelated types.

Comment: @Holt The intention is to make an SOA type thing where the elements are different for different `Cont`s and are of varying sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use type erasure.

```
struct ContainerBase
{
  virtual ~ContainerBase() = 0;
  // This is where you can add an interface for common functionality.
  // Write the pure virtual functions here and implement/override them in ContainerTyped.
};

inline ContainerBase::~ContainerBase() = default;

template<class T>
struct ContainerTyped : public ContainerBase
{
  std::vector<T> values;
};

class Cont
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ContainerBase>> containers;

public:
  Cont(int mask) {
    // ...
    if ((mask & fooMask) > 0)
      containers.push_back(std::make_unique<ContainerTyped<Foo>>());
    if ((mask & barMask) > 0)
      containers.push_back(std::make_unique<ContainerTyped<Bar>>());
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/fPxv9h)

This is probably more suitable than using e.g. `std::any` or other preexisting type erasure because 1) you specify that only specific things (your vector containers) can be stored, and 2) you can add a common interface as indicated and even specialize the interface functions in the differently `ContainerTyped`. But we would need to know more about your use case to detail this benefit.

The problem with `void*` is always that you need to somehow retain information about what you actually stored because you are circumventing the strong type system. In other words, how would you get the stored thing *back* into the strong type system? This is exactly the part where the above approach can shine because you could add a `virtual print() = 0` in `ContainerBase` and then create specialized versions for each kind of struct, e.g.

```
template<>
void ContainerTyped<Foo>::print()
{
    for (Foo& foo : values) {
        // Print Foo objects as you wish!
    }
}
```

---

In terms of not having to touch the `Cont` constructor when adding a `Qux` struct, you obviously still need to encode the information of "which mask bit belongs to which struct" somehow, but you can extract it from the `Cont` constructor (and even hide it in a different translation unit):

```
// Put this implementation wherever, Cont only has to know the signature.
std::unique_ptr<ContainerBase> makeContainer(int mask, unsigned indexBit)
{
  if ((mask & fooMask) > 0)
    return std::make_unique<ContainerTyped<Foo>>();
  // etc.
  if ((mask & quxMask) > 0)
    return std::make_unique<ContainerTyped<Qux>>();
  return nullptr;
}

// ...

Cont::Cont(int mask)
{
  for (unsigned indexBit = 0; indexBit < 8; ++indexBit) {
    auto container = makeContainer(mask, indexBit);
    if (container)
      containers.emplace_back(std::move(container));
  }
}
```

You can go about other ways of encoding that enum -> type information, but that's beyond the scope of this question. The key is that you can hide your concrete type behind `ContainerBase` and use that everywhere you want to refer to "any one of those Containers".

Comment: This solves the `void**` problem but not the hardcoded types in `Cont` problem. Is there a way of doing this with some sort of metaprogramming thing?

Comment: Yes. `std::unique_ptr<ContainerBase> makeContainer(int mask, unsigned bitIndex)`. Adding this to the answer.

Comment: I preferably wanted to have a `#define TYPES Foo, Bar, Baz, Qux` and then use template meta-programming to get the nth type, but in that case n would have to be constant and known at compile time and could not be iterated in a loop. Therefore, I think what I want is probably impossible.

Comment: That's possible too, e.g. with variadic templates. But please ask a new question for that ("how do I select a concrete implementation type based on a runtime value"), or research that problematique if you think this sounds like something people have asked before.